# Capture web page data using native language code

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, desktop-application, node-webkit

I'm looking for leads on how to capture web page metadata from the current browser page. I want to create a feature in my application that will allow the user to press a hot key and record meta data from the web page currently open in the user's browser. My application will be running minimized, this feature is to be activated by a global hot key.

I'm using nw.js (formerly Node-Webkit) to create this application, so ideally, the solution would be javascript running in a desktop installation of Node.js. If this is not practical, I understand that I can call platform specific code from nw.js, so solutions developed in any desktop os language would be of interest.

My application targets OS X and Windows.

I'm hoping to capture metadata from all major modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 10+).

At a minimum I need to capture the page url, but I also want to capture Keywords, Description and highlighted text for the source web page.

I need to implement this function without modifying the source webpage in any way, and I prefer to avoid the need for browser extensions, bookmarklets or plugins.

If a solution exists using a remote controlled browser extension (no user interaction) that would be of interest, but ideally I want to avoid requiring the end user to install or interact with anything but my application.

My search to date has located no information on reading web page information from applications outside the browser.

Any thoughts or leads are much appreciated.

Comment: The metadata you're asking about is static on the page.  There is no need to use a browser to do anything... simply parse the HTML.  It would be in the same in every browser.

Comment: Two problems there: 1) my app does not know the URL. and 2) I want the user to be able to highlight text in the browser before hitting my app's hot key. I have Javascript to do these things, but I want to avoid requiring the user to install a bookmarklet or extension.

Comment: I really don't know how you expect to be able to use browser data without a browser extension.  There are some nasty hacks you can use depending on OS to get some information, but not in any useful way.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the perspective, I'm not interested in nasty hacks.

Comment: In that case, I think browser extensions are the way to go for what you need.

Comment: As I understand you want to make application which will track what pages user open? I think it's gonna be hard